# ModPagespeedDisallow - Internal Server error (Page speed)

Tags: performance, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I don't know why, but when I upgraded my "pagespeed" to version 1.3 some features stopped.

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>  
  ModPagespeed On
  
  ModPagespeedDomain http://www.example.com

#  ModPageSpeedDisallow stopped :(
#  ModPageSpeedDisallow */page/*
#  ModPageSpeedDisallow */anotherpage/*

 
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters outline_javascript 
 
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_images
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_images
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_jpeg 
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_png
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_gif_to_png
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_images

  ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
 
  ModPagespeedEnableFilters outline_css

  ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_to_head,move_css_above_scripts
</IfModule>
```

ModPageSpeedDisallow stopped working. When I enabled (removed the "#"). I got an internal server error.

Does anyone know why? What do I have to do?

**updated**

Error message:

```
/path/.htaccess: Unknown directive ModPageSpeedDisallow
```

**updated - 07/03/2013**

In the new version (1.3 beta), the "command" is case-sensitive. I changed from:

```
ModPageSpeedDisallow
```

to:

```
ModPagespeedDisallow
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the error? Feel free to contact us directly at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mod-pagespeed-discuss or https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/list

Comment: hi @sligocki ! 
I edited my question with the error information. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed on the mailing list, the command is case-sensitive. You need

```
ModPagespeedDisallow
```

Did it allow the other version in the past? Perhaps we should make it case-insensitive again.